# Speech recognition Sphinx4 Hindi

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I am trying to work on Hindi speech recognition. I am getting the error in setting paths of models. I am setting them like shown below. Where am I going wrong?

```
configuration  
.setAcousticModelPath("file:///C/Users//Desktop/hindi/model_parameters/hindi.cd_cont_1000");
configuration
.setDictionaryPath("file:///C/Users/apurvgandhwani/Desktop/hindi/etc/hindi.dic");
configuration
.setLanguageModelPath("file:///C/Users/apurvgandhwani/Desktop/hindi/etc/lm/hindi.arpa");
```

Comment: improved formatting and Grammer

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: edu.cmu.sphinx.util.Utilities.pathJoin(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
 at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Context.setAcousticModel(Context.java:89)
 at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Context.<init>(Context.java:61)
 at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Context.<init>(Context.java:45)
 at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.AbstractSpeechRecognizer.<init>(AbstractSpeechRecognizer.java:44)
 at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.StreamSpeechRecognizer.<init>(StreamSpeechRecognizer.java:35)
 at com.example.TranscriberDemo.main(TranscriberDemo.java:24)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you need to make several steps:

1. Make sure only recent sphinx4 in your classpath, you only need
   sphinx4-core-5prealpha.jar, not old sphinx4.jar
2. Fix path to be proper URL, it should be `file:///C:`, not `file:///C/`
3. Get model from sphinx4 website, it contains additional file `feat.params`

Overall, model for Hindi is not accurate yet, once we have more data to train it will become more accurate and usable.

Further details [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/sphinx4/thread/82bd6c1b/)